# Angular2-Meteor: @Injectable decorator not working

Tags: angular2-meteor

I am creating an Angular2-Meteor project. I have set it up my to use Angular 2 RC5. Everything works nicely until I try to add a service using the @injectable() decorator. As soon as it's added I receive a meteor compile error:

> reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

As soon as I remove the @injectable() decorator Meteor compiles everything and I can load my application.

I have the barbatus:angular2-polyfills package installed which I think is all that is needed to import the required zone.js and reflect-metadata package. Someone has suggested using imports at the top of the main.ts but that doesn't work.

The @NgModule and @component decorators are working without a problem. As I have yet to wire the service (that uses the @injectable decorator) up to my @ngmodule I think this indicates that the Meteor environment simply isn't handling the @injectable decorator as intended. Regardless of whether it is used or not.

Any advice or ideas on how to solve this issue would be much appreciated.

JT

The meteor packages installed are:

```
meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.12                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var@1.0.10            # Reactive variable for tracker
jquery@1.11.9                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.1.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library
standard-minifier-css@1.2.0   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@1.2.0    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.14                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.5.8              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

autopublish@1.0.7             # Publish all data to the clients (for prototyping)
insecure@1.0.7                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
angular2-compilers
barbatus:angular2-runtime
practicalmeteor:mocha
xolvio:cleaner
hwillson:stub-collections
dispatch:mocha-phantomjs
shell-server
barbatus:angular2-polyfills
```

The npm packages from `package.json` installed are:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^0.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
    "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
    "@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
    "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
    "angular2-meteor": "^0.7.0-beta.1",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "^0.1.1",
    "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "^0.0.2",
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1",
    "codelyzer": "latest",
    "tslint": "latest",
    "typescript": "latest",
    "typings": "latest"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Move your file under the 'imports' folder](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/380).